# Transição de activities com classes serializable (getIntent problem)

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, serialização, android-intent

Eu tenho um problema ao passar uma classe serializable. Eu insiro-a no Bundle da seguinte forma.

```
public void voltarMain(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    myIntent.putExtra("Cliente", cliente);

    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Quando eu tento recebe-la na segunda activity ela está no Bundle mas dá-me um erro de "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.math.RoundingMode.ordinal()' on a null object reference"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a forma como tento obtê-la.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o erro obtido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota: Num tablet Huawei MediaPad T5 (android 8.0) funciona corretamente enquanto que este erro me surge num samsung A7 2018 (android 9.0)

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de criar um Bundle e colocar no seu intent, coloque seu objeto cliente com a função putExtra da classe Intent:

```
Intent intent = (...)
i.putExtra("Cliente", cliente);
```

P.S.: use o bloco de código do próprio stack overflow, que vai se adaptar ao tamanho da tela, e permite que as pessoas copiem o texto facilmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do bloco de código. Quanto à solução apresentada também já experimentei e com o mesmo resultado :(

Comment: Você já tentou colocar um breakpoint na função startActivity pra ver se o intent tem o extra que você colocou? É estranho não ter funcionado porque eu sempre uso desse jeito e nunca tive problema.

Comment: O mais estranho é que num tablet android 8 funciona perfeitamente e num telemovel android 9 já nao da